# Make a values of column into new column and check for duplicates in other column ,print status color in the value column if other column duplicated

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column A,B,C,D A column has value x1,x2,x3,x4,x5 create a column x1,x2,x3,x4,x5 and print 1 if B,C,D has a duplication

Please provide an answer using pyspark or python pandas

Input

```
A   B   C   D  status_color

X1  a   b   c   red

X2  a   a   b   green

X3  a   a   b    red

X4  a   b   c   green
```

Output

```
B   C   D   X1  X2  X3  X4

a   b   c   red 0   0   green

a   a   b   0   green   red 0
```

I tried to find duplicate of column and then create a column duplicate flag which prints status_color if other column are duplicated
df['duplicate_flag']=df.duplicated(subset['B','C','D'])

my problem here i don't know to compare it with column A and print it in X1,X2,X3,X4

any one can help with python? i am new to python

Answer (score 2):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
group = df.groupby(["B", "C", "D"], sort=False).agg("|".join)
res = group["A"].str.get_dummies().reset_index()
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   B  C  D  X1  X2  X3  X4
0  a  a  b   0   1   1   0
1  a  b  c   1   0   0   1
```

Comment: Is this answer can be written in pyspark using same groupby and aggregate or we have to use other function?

Comment: @SowmiyadeviK I'm not familiar with pyspark, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
out = (pd.crosstab([df['B'], df['C'], df['D']], df['A'])
         .clip(upper=1) # only if you expect duplicates
         .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
       )
```

output:

```
   B  C  D  X1  X2  X3  X4
0  a  a  b   0   1   1   0
1  a  b  c   1   0   0   1
```